# Access interface types inside database interface types file

Tags: typescript-typings, supabase-database

New to Typescript.
I am struggling to figure out how to access and use the interface values in my database types export as interfaces in my code.

I don't want to create new seperate interfaces if my database types export already provides them.

Here is a sample of the interface export from Supabase in my 'types.ts' file:

```
export interface Database {
  graphql_public: {
    Tables: {
      [_ in never]: never
    }
    Views: {
      [_ in never]: never
    }
    Functions: {
      graphql: {
        Args: {
          operationName?: string
          query?: string
          variables?: Json
          extensions?: Json
        }
        Returns: Json
      }
    }
    Enums: {
      [_ in never]: never
    }
    CompositeTypes: {
      [_ in never]: never
    }
  }
  public: {
    Tables: {
      expenses: {
        Row: {
          amount: number
          category: string
          created_at: string | null
          date: string
          description: string | null
          file_names: string[] | null
          id: number
        }
        Insert: {
          amount: number
          category: string
          created_at?: string | null
          date: string
          description?: string | null
          file_names?: string[] | null
          id?: never
        }
        Update: {
          amount?: number
          category?: string
          created_at?: string | null
          date?: string
          description?: string | null
          file_names?: string[] | null
          id?: never
        }
        Relationships: [
          {
            foreignKeyName: "expenses_organisation_id_fkey"
            columns: ["organisation_id"]
            referencedRelation: "organisations"
            referencedColumns: ["id"]
          },
          {
            foreignKeyName: "expenses_uuid_fkey"
            columns: ["uuid"]
            referencedRelation: "profiles"
            referencedColumns: ["uuid"]
          },
          {
            foreignKeyName: "expenses_vehicle_id_fkey"
            columns: ["vehicle_id"]
            referencedRelation: "vehicles"
            referencedColumns: ["id"]
          }
        ]
      }
      logs: {
        Row: {
          created_at: string | null
          error: string | null
          function: string | null
          id: number
          value: number | null
        }
        Insert: {
          created_at?: string | null
          error?: string | null
          function?: string | null
          id?: number
          value?: number | null
        }
        Update: {
          created_at?: string | null
          error?: string | null
          function?: string | null
          id?: number
          value?: number | null
        }
        Relationships: []
      }
      notification_preferences: {
        Row: {
          function_name: string
          id: number
          organisation_id: number
          vehicle_id: number
        }
        Insert: {
          function_name: string
          id?: number
          organisation_id: number
          vehicle_id: number
        }
        Update: {
          function_name?: string
          id?: number
          organisation_id?: number
          vehicle_id?: number
        }
        Relationships: [
          {
            foreignKeyName: "notification_preferences_organisation_id_fkey"
            columns: ["organisation_id"]
            referencedRelation: "organisations"
            referencedColumns: ["id"]
          },
          {
            foreignKeyName: "notification_preferences_vehicle_id_fkey"
            columns: ["vehicle_id"]
            referencedRelation: "vehicles"
            referencedColumns: ["id"]
          }
        ]
      }
      notifications: {
        Row: {
          created_at: string
          dismissed_at: string | null
          emails: string[] | null
          emails_sent: boolean | null
        }
        Insert: {
          created_at?: string
          dismissed_at?: string | null
          emails?: string[] | null
          emails_sent?: boolean | null
        }
        Update: {
          created_at?: string
          dismissed_at?: string | null
          emails?: string[] | null
          emails_sent?: boolean | null
        }
        Relationships: [
          {
            foreignKeyName: "notifications_expense_id_fkey"
            columns: ["expense_id"]
            referencedRelation: "expenses"
            referencedColumns: ["id"]
          },
          {
            foreignKeyName: "notifications_organisation_id_fkey"
            columns: ["organisation_id"]
            referencedRelation: "organisations"
            referencedColumns: ["id"]
          },
          {
            foreignKeyName: "notifications_reminder_id_fkey"
            columns: ["reminder_id"]
            referencedRelation: "reminders"
            referencedColumns: ["id"]
          },
          {
            foreignKeyName: "notifications_vehicle_id_fkey"
            columns: ["vehicle_id"]
            referencedRelation: "vehicles"
            referencedColumns: ["id"]
          }
        ]
      }
```

I import the file..
import { Database } from "../_shared/interfaces.ts";

And would normall create an interface this way:

```
interface Expense {
  id: number;
  expense_category: string;
}
```

But I want to get it from the Database interface so I don't have to create it separately if that makes sense, for example:

```
interface Expense extends Database.public.expenses...
```

But nothing of this kind works, not sure if I am trying something that is not standard at all, but it seems that it should be? I am trying to use these interfaces in my Supabase functions.

Thank you

Comment: Try `Database["public"]["expenses"]`. Dot notation doesn't work for types, to subscript a type you need to use bracket notation. Also maybe you meant `Database["public"]["Table"]["expenses"]`, because it seems to me that `Database["public"]` type doesn't have an `expenses` property.

Comment: @AlexChashin Works exactly this way, thank you! Didn't think it would be how it's done.   reminder: Database['public']['Tables']['reminders']['Insert'],
  vehicle: Database['public']['Tables']['vehicles']['Insert'], - Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dot notation doesn't work for types, use bracket notation instead:

```
interface Expense extends Database["public"]["expenses"] {
  // ...
}
```